# Jasmine test Instantiation of objects in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for an Angular2 project and I have a problem with testing something like following. Expect headers object created and append method has been called with correct parameters. Is there a simple way to do it ?

```
myFunction ( ){

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );

}
```

I need to complete

```
describe('myFunction', function() {

    it('should create headers object', function(){

    });
    it('should call append in headers object with name and value', function(){

    });        

});
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: I don't know how to unit test it

Comment: What do you want to test?

Comment: What do you want to test about it?

Comment: I edited the question.. hope it's clear now

Comment: @MarkTimothy `myFunction()` is a complete useless function, if you don't return the headers or bind them to something.

Comment: Ah yes.. function is just an example.. I need to test that two lines , please forget about the rest of the function

Answer (score 1):

```
myFunction ( ){

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    return headers;
}
```

```
describe('myFunction', function() {

    it('should create headers object', function(){
      let headers = myFunction();
      headers.forEach((values: string[], name: string, headers: Map<string, string[]>) => {
        // do check with each passed header
      });
    });
    it('should call append in headers object with name and value', function(){

    });        

});
```